# random_device выдает одни и те же значения при каждой компиляции

Tags: c++

[image: На скрине видно, что вроде как значения изначально разные выдает, но только очень приближенно к минимуму] На скрине видно, что вроде как значения изначально разные выдает, но только очень приближенно к минимуму В чем может быть проблема?

```
Struktura **Lososwanie(const int size){

  random_device randomDevice;
  default_random_engine randomEngine(randomDevice());
  uniform_int_distribution<int> intRange(int_min, int_max);
  uniform_real_distribution<float> letterRange(min_char, 
  max_char);

  if (size > 0)
  {
      Struktura **struktury = new Struktura*[size];

      for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
          struktury[i] = new Struktura(intRange(randomEngine), 
   min_float + i, static_cast<char>(letterRange(randomEngine)));

      return struktury;
  }
  else
      return nullptr;
```

Comment: Вы же говорили, что каждый раз одинаковые значения? А теперь вдруг стали разные?

Comment: Какое отношение ваши скриншоты имеют к приведенному вами огрызку кода?

Comment: Значения отличаются минимально, поэтому не заметила изначально.

Answer (score 3):

Вы используете MinGW?

`random_device` не работает нормально на MinGW, используйте что-то другое. Самый простой вариант - `std::time(0)`.

Answer (score 1):

Вот так будет выдавать разные ответы:

```
float random(float from, float to)
{

    std::random_device randomDevice;
    std::mt19937_64 mt(randomDevice());
    std::uniform_real_distribution<> distribution(from, to);
    return distribution(mt);

}
```

Ну и можете заменить real на int destribution.